# TypeScript - narrow type by function asserts

Tags: typescript, return-type, type-assertion, type-narrowing

I'm trying to get TS to narrow a type that I am manually modifying in a function:

```
interface Node {
  parent: string | null;
}

interface NoParent extends Node {
  parent: null;
}

interface HasParent extends Node {
  parent: string;
}

// Node -> HasParent
// ok, Node now known to have parent
export const setParent = (n: Node): asserts n is HasParent => {
  n.parent = 'parent added';
};

// Node -> NoParent
// ok, Node now known to have no parent
export const unsetParent = (n: Node): asserts n is NoParent => {
  n.parent = null;
};

// NoParent -> HasParent
// error: A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
export const addParent = (n: NoParent): asserts n is HasParent => {
  // ... use n as NoParent ...

  (n as Node).parent = 'parent';
};

// HasParent -> NoParent
// error: A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
export const removeParent = (n: HasParent): asserts n is NoParent => {
  // ... use n as HasParent ...

  (n as Node).parent = null;
};
```

I need to write `addParent` and `removeParent` with a specific type (not `Node`) because those functions also serve as type guards in calling code. Is there a way to tell TS that I know the object I'm returning is a type that is not compatible with the parameter?

Comment: I think you don't event need both `removeParent` and `addParent`, because they are same as `setParent` & `unsetParent`

Comment: They are the same at runtime, yes, but I need the parameter types of `removeParent` and `addParent` for type safety at the calling sites.

Comment: This is a lot easier if you return a new object (`return ({...node, parent: null});`, etc.) rather than modifying an object and returning `void`.

Comment: @captain-yossarian is right.  `HasParent extends Node`, so you can pass either `HasParent` or `Node` into `unsetParent`.  The returned type is `NoParent` in both situations.

Comment: @LindaPaiste: that doesn't work; functions which 'assert' have `void` return type. In any case, I'm not looking to return anything, I need the `asserts ...` type narrowing following the function call at the call site.

Comment: TS does not play well with mutation